# UICollectionView two rows on each scroll page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to achieve such effect using Collection View :

[UICollectionView image](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2h6vnfl.jpg)

Width of these cells should auto resize to width of the screen. Heights of each cell should be like 45% (10% is for this black gap). I tried a lot of combinations but I cannot achieve this in any way. Thank's in advance for any help.
Best regards, 
Adrian.

Comment: Have you tried to use uicollectionviewflowlayout?

Comment: Have you tried using two collection views for each 45% of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the collectionView width to full screen. Implement these delegate method

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, height);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottom, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate! It worked, tho I had to change `return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, height);` to `collectionView.bounds.size.width, collectionView.bounds.size.height/2`

Answer (score 0):

I have attached an image here 
[image]

I have taken a CollectionView Cell fitting the size of the width of the screen and half the size of the screen, taken a UIView and dropped it inside the collection view cell with a padding of 10-15 px from the bottom, clear the colour of the collection view background and that should give u the illusion of the CollectionViewCell cells having a padding to each other.
Whatever elements you want to show in the CollectionView Please add it to the view inside the view inside the CollectionViewCell cell